# AngularJS - Large sets of data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been pondering moving our current admin system over to a JS framework for a while and I tested out AngularJS today. I really like how powerful it is. I created a demo application (source: https://github.com/andyhmltn/portfolio-viewer) that has a list of 'items' and displays them in a paginated list that you can order/search in realtime.

The problem that I'm having is figuring out how I would replicate this kind of behaviour with a larger data set. Ideally, I want to have a table of items that's sortable/searchable and paginated that's all in realtime.

The part that concerns me is that this table will have 10,000+ records at least. At current, that's no problem as it's a PHP file that limits the query to the current page and appends any search options to the end. The demo above only has about 15-20 records in. I'm wondering how hard it would be to do the same thing with such a large amount of records without pulling all of them into one JSON request at once as it'll be incredibly slow.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why not just synthesize 10000 records? (or just append the same 25 ones 400 times?) Then you'll see for yourself. And if that won't work you can even mix-and-match: a client side application with server-side paging and sorting.

Comment: Sorry, I fail to grasp the point: you want to download all the record to the client or not?

Comment: Preferably not. I'm just trying to think of an alternative at the moment

Answer (score 4):

I'm used to handle large datasets in JavaScript, and I would suggest you to :

- use **pagination** (either server-sided or client-sided, depending on the actual volume of your data, see below)
- use [Crossfilter.js](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) to group your records and adopt a several-levels architecture in your GUI (records per month, double click, records per day for the clicked month, etc.)

An indicator I often use is the following :

```
rowsAmount x columnsAmount x dataManipulationsPerRow
```

Also, consider the fact that *handling* large datasets and *displaying* them are two very differents things.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed pulling so many rows in one request would be a killer. Fortunately Angular has the [ng-grid component](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) that can do server-side paging (among many other things). Instructions are provided in the given link.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll look into it and then see if it solves what I'm trying to achieve :)

Comment: I tried ng-grid in my project and found it to not be ready for prime time.  At the time of my trial, at least, the grid didn't have footer-row (summary) capabilities.  It is also implemented as a set of DIVs instead of a table.  At first, this doesn't seem so bad, but for some reason, the text isn't selectable.  Even if it were, without the semantic meaning of the `table`, users can't copy/paste into Excel.  It made me sad, but it turned out that I was able to write my own full-featured, paging, sorting grid in Angular in less than 80 lines of code.

Comment: @BrianGenisio Text selection in ng-grid is disabled via CSS by default.  Probably to make row selection a bit prettier.  If you want it back turn it back on via CSS.  `user-select: text !important`